# How to curve a plane using a 3d point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, 3d

I don't really know how to describe this, but what I want is to have a plane like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/supereggbert/aff58196188816576af0) and draw a 3d point on it. The point is scaled between [-1,1]. The plane should then adapt the other coordinates to generate a curve/net. There will only ever be one point as an input.

I managed to draw the point with the above example by adding the following code (I rescaled the point before).

```
var surfaces=[
{
  name: 'Point',
  data: dataFromFormular(function(x,y){
    if(x == point.x && y == point.y)
        return -point.z;

      return 0;
    })
},
```

But I can't really figure out how to transform the other coordinates to generate the *thing* that looks like those black holes (eg. [here](http://casswww.ucsd.edu/archive/public/tutorial/images/gr_geom.gif)).

I thought about generating parabolas between "0 to point.x" and "point.x to 1" and multiply by point.y, but I don't know how to factor y into that and how to scale properly.

I'm also open to other ways to do this more elegantly as I'm not sure if `d3` is the correct tool for this (I changed the scale of the example from "-20 to 20" to "0 to 100" and it seems really laggy so far.)

Comment: 3D is difficult, especially if you are new to coding. Would a 2D curve be acceptable?

Comment: The point I have is 3d and I'm required to "visualize" this point. I'm very comfortable with coding and javascript in itself, but the last time I did 3d was a few years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of generating *height functions* to produce results similar to what you want. A good one would be the *Gaussian distribution*:

```
data: dataFromFormular(function(x,y){
       var dx = x - point.x, dy = y - point.y;
       return A * point.z * exp(-B*(dx*dx + dy*dy));
    })
```

`A` and `B` are positive parameters. `A` defines how deep the "hole" is, and `B` is inversely proportional to how wide it is.